# What is this plant with spiky leaves found on a beach in Indonesia?

Tags: identification, perennials

Some time ago I found a plant on Depok Beach ([Yogyakarta, Indonesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogyakarta)).

This is what it looks like:

[image]

It looks like spiky leaves that grow from its branches. The leaves are actually quite hard: you could hurt your finger if you touch the end point.

I know it's not aloe.

I'd like to know what it is called but I haven't found the answer, yet.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely [*Spinifex littoreus*](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Ravan's%20Moustache.html) - this plant is well adapted to growing in sand dunes or sand beaches. The leaves are reduced to spiny projections as protection against high temperatures and dry conditions in sand.

Comment: I was hoping someone would get this - that's actually why I edited the question.:) Looks like a correct ID.